# creating an instagram bot with reading an excel file and posing on Instagram, but some of words can not be read properly

Tags: python, excel, instagram

```
from instabot import Bot
import openpyxl
import smtplib

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="xxx", password="xxx")

filepath = "C:/Users/Username/OneDrive/Desktop/excel/instagram2.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("insta")
for i in range(2,7):
    bot_name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    price = sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
    title = sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value
    hashtag = sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value
    url = sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value
    description = str(title+"\n\n"+price+"\n\n"+hashtag+"\n\n"+url)
    img = "C:/Users/Username/OneDrive/Desktop/instagram/instagram.bot"+str(i)+".jpg"
    bot.upload_photo(img,caption=description)
```

I created an Instagram bot for myself. The descriptions of my posts are on Excel. When the programm posts on Instagram, Only the URL can not be recognised as the actual URL, but as a series of words. So when you click the "URL", you can not jump into the URL site. How can I let the programm recognise it as a URL?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you get currently (for img) and how you want it to look?

Comment: (account name) test1

100 euro

#mountain #climbing #safe #nomountainnolife

https://www.amazon.de/

Comment: this is the result when I let the programming post, but the link of amazon.de is not clickable.

Comment: I want to let it clickable and reach the link, but currently i have no idea how to make codes for it.